# Calculating a value in Excel from several columns based on the lookup row in a different column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

As I'm new to Excel, I would like to find the best way to learn formulas, So please guide me to learn it.

For report purposes, we need a formula which can do the following calculation:

It should look into the `Used %` column and search for the lowest value.  On that row, it should calculate from the second and third columns: `(Total - Used)/1024`, and print the Value in a new location where the formula is written.

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦══════╦════════╗
║ Names ║ Total ║ Used ║ Used % ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬══════╬════════╣
║ KTM   ║ 10000 ║ 1500 ║ 15.00% ║ *Here is the lowest value in %
║ GCC   ║ 10000 ║ 2000 ║ 20.00% ║
║ TMT   ║ 12000 ║ 5000 ║ 41.67% ║
║ HMT   ║  9000 ║ 6000 ║ 66.67% ║
║ RCC   ║ 15000 ║ 8000 ║ 53.33% ║
║ AUJ   ║ 10000 ║ 6700 ║ 67.00% ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩══════╩════════╝
```

In this example, the lowest Used % is in the first row, so `Total - Used` equals `8500`, and the result would be `8500/1024`.

I can get the MIN value from the percentage but I'm unable to do the rest of the calculation.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. You said you want to take the lowest value from the used% column which is 15% and subtract (Total - used) /1024 so wouldn't this be 15 - [(10000-1500)/1024] = 6.7 for the first line based on what you said? You may need to clarify a bit better with some examples. Please edit your question with a few examples

Comment: @EricF I have mentioned the exact requirement to my very first question which is was then edited. And I got the answer to my question which is working absolutely working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it in to parts:

1. Find the lowest value formula =MIN(D:D)

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/min.php

2. Find the row of the lowest value =MATCH(MIN(D:D),D:D,0)

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a

3. Use INDEX to select the total from the found row =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MIN(D:D),D:D,0))

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd

4. Put it all together: B - C / 1024

   ```
   =(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MIN(D:D),D:D,0))-INDEX(C:C,MATCH(MIN(D:D),D:D,0)))/1024
   ```

NOTE:
This assumes that your columns are as shown in your example.

EDIT: I updated the answer from INDIRECT to INDEX after reading about formula volatility. TIL
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/04/25/indirect-excels-most-evil-function/

EDIT2: Changed formula to reflect from B - D to B - C as described in OP.

Comment: @Shanker, the output is different from what?

Comment: its proper now its working as expected.